# Mandrill webhooks timeout error

Tags: mysql, apache, webhooks, mandrill

I have been using Mandrill webhooks from a long time and till now I haven't encountered this error.

[image: Screenshot from Mandrillapp.com]

But now I see this error, I am not sure what has caused this ?

Please let me know why this might be happening and what might be the possible solution for the same.

Is it related to my server handling capacity because I have checked for that as well and Mandrill doesnt have too many concurrent request that it is sending to my Apache server, so according to me that is not an issue and also mysql also doesn't seem to be causing the bottleneck, but then I I have not used any benchmarking tool to determine the same.

Please let me know the solution if you guys have encountered something like this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the URL is not responding to the request. There could be a few reasons:

- If the URL points to an internal server, a firewall could be blocking it or a port number (if given).
- Once set up the webhook will send via a POST HTTP verb, however for testing it sends a HEAD request. Quite often web servers (e.g. IIS) will limit what verbs they respond to and will only respond to GET and POST requests.

If that's working your URL should respond with just **headers only** to acknowledge the request. (HEAD doesn't allow any page content to be sent) so it should only do something like this for a HEAD request:

```
<?php  header( 'Content-Type:' ); // returning 200 ?>
```

More details on their site
http://help.mandrill.com/entries/22024856-Why-can-t-my-webhook-or-inbound-route-URL-be-verified-

You may wish to try this tool to see what HTTP header result is being returned (if any) or if another error is being returned, just remember that if the URL is internal, it could be blocked to the outside world.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en